# VB.NET and IME KeyUp event

Tags: vb.net, cjk, ime

I am trying to figure out how to determine when a user is "done" typing and ready to hit the enter key when using the Japanese IME in Windows.

I'm trying capture the "final" Enter key, since the event can fire more than once if the user is selecting different entries while typing in Japanese.

For example, while typing "駅に行く," when the character 駅 is typed, the user may select a different character from the IME list, but this requires hitting the enter key to make the selection. This will fire the key events in VB.NET. The same with the typing 行く. The entries are highlighted with an underline until the user has made a selection, at which point they can continue typing.

What I'm "trying" to do is wait until the entire sentence has been typed and the user hits the Enter key so that I can now manipulate the entering text string.

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You could try caching events in class [TextCompositionManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.textcompositionmanager?view=net-5.0), hopefully `PreviewTextInput` event is the one you are interested in.

Note that IMEs have different behaviors for completing an entry. You may want to see some [language examples here](https://github.com/Tennyleaz/IME-Events).

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will take a look.

I kind of put this issue on the backburner, but I appreciate the response.